# Can't set TCP source Port with boost asio

Tags: sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio, nat-traversal

Usually it does not matter which source port you send data from as a client, but I still want to do it for some testing. 
So I tried to bind my client's socket to a specific port but even when I'm running client and server on my local machine (with localhost as dest address) the server tells me that my source port is something like 59000. 
I initialize my socket like this:

```
tcp::socket socket(io_service,tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),2000));
```

Is it possible to do what I intend?
I'm trying to find out if my router changes ports when the message goes through it. 
Thats for NAT traversal stuff I'm playing around with at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binding a socket to a specific port can be done exactly as posted in the question:

```cpp
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::socket socket(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 2000));
assert(socket.local_endpoint().port() == 2000); // true
```

In this case, the `socket` object will be [constructed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload3.html), opening and binding to the local [endpoint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/basic_endpoint/overload2.html) with an address of `INADDR_ANY` and port `2000`.

The local endpoint is likely changing as a result of how the connection is being established.  When the connect operation is initiated from either the [`socket.connect()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/connect.html) or [`socket.async_connect()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_connect.html) member functions, the socket will attempt to connect to the remote endpoint, opening the socket if necessary.  Therefore, when invoked on a socket that is already open, the socket's local endpoint will not change.

On the other hand, when the connect operation is initiated from either [`connect()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/connect.html) or [`async_connect()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html) free functions, the socket is closed before attempting to connect to any endpoint.  Thus, the socket will bind to an unspecified port.  The parameter section on the free functions documentation defines this behavior:

> The `socket` to be connected. If the `socket` is already open, it will be closed.

Furthermore, there is no clean way to control this behavior, as the `socket.close()` and `socket.connect()` member functions are invoked one after another within the [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.55.0/include/boost/asio/impl/connect.hpp#L121-L122).

---

Here is a complete example demonstrating the behaviors described above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

// This example is not interested in the handlers, so provide a noop function
// that will be passed to bind to meet the handler concept requirements.
void noop() {}

// Helper function used to initialize the client socket.
void force_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& client_socket)
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  client_socket.close();
  client_socket.open(tcp::v4());
  client_socket.bind(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 2000));
  std::cout << "client socket: " << client_socket.local_endpoint()
            << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
  tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Initiate the connect operation directly on the socket.
  server_socket.close();
  force_endpoint(client_socket);
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, boost::bind(&noop));
  client_socket.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), boost::bind(&noop));

  // Print endpoints before and after running the operations.
  io_service.run();
  std::cout << "After socket.async_connect(): "
            << client_socket.local_endpoint() << std::endl;

  // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Initiate the connection operation with the free async_connect function.
  server_socket.close();
  force_endpoint(client_socket);
  acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, boost::bind(&noop));
  boost::asio::async_connect(
      client_socket,
      tcp::resolver(io_service).resolve(
        tcp::resolver::query("127.0.0.1", 
          boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(acceptor.local_endpoint().port()))),
      boost::bind(&noop));

  // Run the service, causing the client to connect to the acceptor.
  io_service.reset();
  io_service.run();
  std::cout << "After async_connect(): " 
            << client_socket.local_endpoint() << std::endl;
}
```

Which produced the following output:

```
client socket: 0.0.0.0:2000
After socket.async_connect(): 127.0.0.1:2000
client socket: 0.0.0.0:2000
After async_connect(): 127.0.0.1:53115
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the work you made! It works now fine. The free function connect is only shown on the boost asio page, not on the home page of asio itself (confused me). I don't get, why the connect (free) function closes the socket in any case. Is that necessary? I think I don't get the concept right, when to use free vs member functions. But thats another question...(but maybe you know...)

Comment: The free function makes 1 or more connection attempts so it closes it so all the connect operations will start with the socket in the same state since it would have to recreate the native socket for the second and later attempts.